# How to build QgsExpressions in python?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, sql, expression

How can I build a feature request expression using variable inside expression?
For example

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
for j in range( y ):
it = vl.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"field_name" = values[ j ]' ) )
```

or (I have also tried sthing like this)

```
it = vl.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"field_name" = values[%d]' % j) )
```

Where could someone study how to build these kind of expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As starting point for studying I would use the [QGIS Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#iterating-over-a-subset-of-features). For further reading with additional examples look at the books Joseph suggests in his answer.

As for your specific problem I would suggest [string substitution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting) like

```
it = vl.getFeatures( QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression ( u'"field_name" = {0}'.format(values[j])) )
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of available books which help teach Python for QGIS. To name a few:

["The Pyqgis Programmer's Guide"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sBuooAEACAAJ&dq=The+Pyqgis+Programmer%27s+Guide&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIk6ik4LrTyAIVQr4UCh0Pwgvg) by Gary Sherman

["QGIS Python Programming Cookbook"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rfirBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=QGIS+Python+Programming+Cookbook&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAGoVChMIv5PO9LrTyAIVgXEUCh0l_wn4#v=onepage&q=QGIS%20Python%20Programming%20Cookbook&f=false) by Joel Lawhead

["Learning Geospatial Analysis with Python"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UR-8AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+Pyqgis+Programmer%27s+Guide&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBGoVChMIk6ik4LrTyAIVQr4UCh0Pwgvg#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Joel Lawhead

["Mastering QGIS"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=D9i6BwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Kurt Menke, Luigi Pirelli, Richard Smith Jr & John Van Hoesen

Hope this helps!