# How would I build the syntax inside a request in the case I wanted to multiply 2 variables?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sql, expression

I would like add something to my previous question
(here: [How to build QgsExpressions in python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167217/how-to-build-qgsexpressions-in-python/167265?noredirect=1#comment248969_167265))

How would I build the syntax inside this request in the case I wanted **field_name** to be also a **variable** pointing to a field name?

And in the case I wanted to multiply two numerical variables inside a request?

```
expression = QgsExpression('variablepointingtofield * variablepointingtolistitem ')
```